# How to get character offset in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textEditor').contents().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 35) {
            alert('# pressed');
            //How to get '#' character offset relative to an iframe
        }
        return true;
    });
```

`#textEditor` is the **id** of **iframe** i am using in my code

**EDIT:** Offset in x-y coordinates, not in number of characters from beginning of iframe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the offset in number of characters from the start of the input, or the offset in x-y-coordinates in the document?

Comment: @Fritst Van Campen offset in x-y coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
console.log(range.getBoundingClientRect()); // left, top, height, width
```